# Disabling scrolling of ViewPager if there's a HorizontalScrollView in fragment

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager component with 2 fragments, controlled by FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter. In each fragment there is a content comprising various buttons HorizontalScrollView's. What I want to achieve is that when the user scrolls (horizontally) the HorizontalScrollView, then the ViewPager won't react on this gesture. But when the user drags the rest fragment content, then it would flip the pages as usually.

How can I make an exception for HorizontalScrollView not to propagate scrolling gestures to ViewPager? Is there some sort of solution out of the box?

Comment: see ViewGroup.requestDisallowInterceptTou
chEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `ViewPager` and override `canScroll()` to return `true` when the user is trying to scroll the `HorizontalScrollView`.

For example, here is similar code for detecting scrolling on a map represented as a `SurfaceView`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.mapsv2.pager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class MapAwarePager extends ViewPager {
  public MapAwarePager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x,
                              int y) {
    if (v instanceof SurfaceView || v instanceof PagerTabStrip) {
      return(true);
    }

    return(super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y));
  }
}
```